# How access control management works in Azure?

Tags: azure, active-directory, cloud, application-security-group

can someone explain how access management on Azure differs from local on-prem Active Directory - DC? For example, on DC and AD we can have local security groups for application authentication and authorization and for share folders,  but how this thing works in Azure for their SaaS and onedrive? Does Azure have the same security groups like AD has? Where can I learn more about this specific architecture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's called Azure Active Directory (AAD). Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis). You can set up groups and policies similarly to how you would in an on-prem AD.

[Here's a comparison of the two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-compare-azure-ad-to-ad).